# gVim python continues to indent after function ends

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I'm seeing strange behavior in my windows gvim -- it will continue to indent after a function ends, even once characters in column 0 have been entered:

```
def foo(k):
  return 42
  """Still indenting"""
# Comment here
  """Still indenting"""
```

Here is my vimrc:

```
colorscheme slate

filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set ai

set backspace=2
set backspace=indent,eol,start

set cindent
autocmd FileType python setlocal foldmethod=indent smartindent shiftwidth=2 ts=2 et cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class
```

And I also have appended the python vim file found here: https://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=21056

Removing autoindent/ai so that only smartindent is being used does not seem to solve the problem... any thoughts?

Comment: I would recommend not setting `cindent` in your vimrc—it really only works well for C (possibly C-like languages).

Comment: Python indenting uses a `indentexpr`. Then, according to `:help C-indenting`,  `cindent`, `autoindent` and `smartindent` are not used.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there's no solution for that: `vim` (or even `Python`) can't detect the end of the function if you don't change the indentation (besides the `return 42`). The comment on first column may seem strange but is not enough to tell `Python` that your function has ended:

```
def test():
    """comment"""
    print("on test")
# comment
    print("still on test")
    return 42
```

If you run `print(test())` you will get:

```
on test
still on test
42
```